# Conversion to GitHub organization breaks Travis CI pro setup

Tags: php, travis-ci

We just converted a GitHub account used as a central hub to all of our private repositories into an organization. We set up all the different permissions and teams and everything on the github level is working fine.

The problem we are facing is regarding our Travis pro account. It doesn't seem to be hooked anymore to our PRs and commits. I try to setup PRs and do commits and nothing happens on Travis, nothing is detected.

What would you advise me to check to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: [This might be a good place to go](http://chat.travis-ci.com/)?

Comment: Indeed, i didn't know that one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The account that was registered on Travis CI Pro was the same account (Makes sense after all) that was used on GitHub as the owner of the repositories before converting to an organization.

Problem is, when you transform a user into an organization, it destroys that user and moves all repos in it to the organization. To manage our Organization, we created a new user and assigned it to the organization as Owner.

Thats where it makes more sense... Delete the old user, create a new one, so obviously, what happens here is that the link between travis ci and github is lost cause the user doesn't exist anymore and the new user has nothing to do with the old one.

Contacting Travis did the job, they moved our subscription from the now phantom account to the new organization and Voila!